# How do I change the properties of a separate row with a newTableView object with the Corona SDK?

Tags: coronasdk

I have an app that submits text to a new row in the newTableView object and also allows the user to delete rows from the newTableView object (and constantly updates the information to a database).

Following the user clicking the delete button on any row, I'd like to iterate through all the indexes of the rows in the newTableView object and if they exist, rename their IDs numerically from 1 to x so that there are no skipped ID numbers.
As far as I can tell, there is no way to access an individual row outside of its own onRowRender or onRowTouch event.

Does this mean that accessing the ID string of all of these rows is impossible from a single button press?

Answer (score 0):

Actually in my application when i add/delete new row means.first i used insert/delete query after that i deleted entire table and array and then recreated.